# Andvanced REST Client ignores a custom Host header

Tags: advanced-rest-client

I am testing my proxy that simply sends a client's request to a proxied server and returns a response back. The current realization requires that the client must send the fully prepared valid request to the proxy (the Host header value must match with a DNS of the predefined in source code proxied server).

Heres my custom request to the proxy that proxies a www.example.com:
[image]

But the result request that ARC sends to the localhost is:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1234
connection: close
```

then it is sent to the www.example.com but the Host header is invalid for it so 404 is returned as a result.

Comment: Did use set up "Native request" in the application settings? The app should accept the headers value. I will test it this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just noticed that this refers to the old version of ARC for Chrome. Support for Chrome apps is scheduled to end soon the the app is no longer supported. Instead, please, install desktop client from https://install.advancedrestclient.com/

To move your data from one app to another follow instructions from https://docs.advancedrestclient.com/moving-from-chrome-application-to-desktop-client